# How to turn key value pair to new key value pair javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello can somebody help me with javascript. I have list of ages store in **age**.

```
age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];
```

The **sumAge** to count duplicate ages.

```
sumAge = age.reduce((acc, datum) => {
    let count= acc[datum];
    acc[datum] = count === undefined ? 1 : ++count;
    return acc;
 }, {});

console.log(sumAge);
```

I want to get my **result** to be like this:

```
{
age:5,
value: 3
},
{
age:13,
value: 2
}
```

Instead of this.

```
{
5: 3 ,
13: 2
}
```

Comment: further add `sumAge = Object.entries(sumAge).map(([age, value]) => ({ age, value }));`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get my result to be like this

The structure in the question is invalid unless you mean you want an array.

Assuming you want an object keyed by the age (but keep reading if you *do* want an array):

```js
const age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];

const sumAge = age.reduce((acc, datum) => {
    let entry = acc[datum];
    if (entry) {
        ++entry.count;
    } else {
        acc[datum] = {age: datum, count: 1};
    }
    return acc;
 }, {});

console.log(sumAge);
```

**But**, this isn't really a use case for `reduce`, it's overcomplicated. Just use a simple `for-of` loop:

```js
const age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];

const sumAge = {};
for (const datum of age) {
    let entry = sumAge[datum];
    if (entry) {
        ++entry.count;
    } else {
        sumAge[datum] = {age: datum, count: 1};
    }
}

console.log(sumAge);
```

---

If you **do** want an array, then as [Rajesh points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769940/how-to-turn-key-value-pair-to-new-key-value-pair-javascript/57770046#comment101975136_57770046), just use `Object.values` on the result:

```js
const age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];

const sumAge = {};
for (const datum of age) {
    let entry = sumAge[datum];
    if (entry) {
        ++entry.count;
    } else {
        sumAge[datum] = {age: datum, count: 1};
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(sumAge));
```

Comment: Probably you need to do `Object.values(sumAge)`

Comment: @Rajesh - Thanks, it's hard to tell what the OP wants, but it *could* be an array. I've updated to add that option, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could get entries of `sumAge` and map them as needed

```js
let age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];

let sumAge = age.reduce((acc, datum) => {
    let count= acc[datum];
    acc[datum] = count === undefined ? 1 : ++count;
    return acc;
 }, {});
 
let arrAge = Object.entries(sumAge).map(([k,v])=>({age: Number(k), count: v})) 

console.log(arrAge);
```

Comment: the `age` should be a Number

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.values`

```js
let age = [5, 5, 13, 5, 13];

let sumAge = age.reduce((acc, datum) => {
  acc[datum] = acc[datum] || { age: datum, value: 0 };
  acc[datum].value += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(sumAge));
```

Answer (score 0):

My reduce has a blank array as the initial value - this becomes the array accumulator. If the object with the key age for the is in the array, the key value is incremented by 1. Otherwise, the object for the key age with initial key value of one is added to the array accumulator. Here's my code

```
const checkAge = (acc, num) => acc.find(elem => elem.age == num);

const arr = [5, 15, 5, 5, 15].reduce((acc,num) => {
    let idx = acc.indexOf(checkAge(acc, num))
    if(idx >= 0) acc[idx].value += 1;
    else acc.push({age: num, value: 1});
    return acc;


}, []);

console.log(arr); //returns [{age: 5, value: 3}, {age:13, value: 2}]
```